# jpql subtract the results of two count functions

Tags: jpa, collections, size, many-to-many, jpql

Please have a look at the end of this post (found another but also not working way). This second way should be the better one, if it functions one day ;)

I have an entity which consists of two many-to-many relations:
MainEntity has many of As and MainEntity has many of Bs, where A and B is of the same type.
Example for the following JQL: If "ob" has got 4 "As" and 5 "Bs" i need the result of -1 in the placeholder "difference" but it allways returns 0. Same using Outer Joins.

```
   String query = "SELECT ob, (COUNT(A) - COUNT(B)) difference" +
        + " FROM MainEntity ob "
        + " JOIN ob.listA A "
        + " JOIN ob.listB B "
        + " GROUP BY ob "
        + " WHERE ob=:PARAM ";
```

The Following Example is working:

```
"SELECT COUNT(A) FROM MainEntity ob JOIN ob.listA A "
        + "WHERE ob=:PARAM"
```

It returns 5 if ob has 5 items in its list "listA". Can anybody help me to construct the right JPQL?

**EDIT:**
This is working:

```
SELECT SIZE(ob.listA) FROM MainEntity ob WHERE ob=:PARAM
```

So, I thought that this could work also:

```
SELECT SIZE(ob.listA) - SIZE(ob.listB) FROM MainEntity ob WHERE ob=:PARAM
```

But it doesnt work - confusing for me! This JPQL throws following Exception:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-6069] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The field [ENTITYINFOERWEITERUNG.ID] in this expression has an invalid table in this context.
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.invalidTableForFieldInExpression(QueryException.java:722)
```

I think its funny, because following JPQL throws same Exception:

```
SELECT SIZE(ob.listA) - SIZE(ob.listA) FROM MainEntity ob WHERE ob=:PARAM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use subqueries in select clause to get two counts with a single select. Unfortunately JPA doesn't support subqueries in select clause. Your options are either to use two queries or native sql.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I Think that, if your answer was correct, that a parameter for count wouldn't make sense. But Count is a function which allows one parameter.

Comment: Count() counts non null values

Comment: Your are right Sami! I wanted to count the non null values in column of "ListA" and subtract the counted value of non null values in column "ListB". Now I found another (not working) way ;) have a look at edit.

Comment: I Think Sami is right. JPQL is not as mighty as I was expecting. For querying more complex data I will use native-SQL in future. JPA also offers good functionality for creating objects from native-SQL queries, what makes me still believe in JPA.